# How to configure Russian keyboard layout (and switch US<->RU by win+space)?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, keyboard, archlinux

I'm trying to configure keyboard layout in console (archlinux) so that I can switch two languages (US <-> RU) by **win+space** combination. There are so many keymaps in the `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/*` and I have know idea what to load and how the actual *switch* between them is configured. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can make change in user config. Change file `/home/%username%/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/keyboard-layout.xml`

For examle:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <channel name="keyboard-layout" version="1.0">
     <property name="Default" type="empty">
         <property name="XkbDisable" type="bool" value="false"/>
         <property name="XkbLayout" type="string" value="us,ru,ua"/>
         <property name="XkbVariant" type="string" value=",,"/>
         <property name="XkbOptions" type="empty">
             <property name="Group" type="string value="grp:win_space_toggle"/>
         </property>
     </property>
</channel>
```